# How do I set a property in python using its string name

Tags: python

How can I set an object property given its name in a string? I have a dictionary being passed to me and I wish to transfer its values into namesake properties using code like this:

```
for entry in src_dict:
      if entry.startswith('can_'):
          tgt_obj[entry] = src_dict_profile[entry]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
setattr(some_object, 'some_attribute', 42)
```

Comment: Please, no semicolons. :-D

Comment: This doesn't use the @property.setter function though does it... how would you set the property through that?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're looking for [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr).

Example:

```
for entry in src_dict:
      if entry.startswith('can_'):
          setattr(tgt_obj, entry, src_dict_profile[entry])
```

Answer (score 1):

On objects that have "**dict**" property

```
if "__dict__" in dir(obj):
```

you may do fun things like:

```
obj.__dict__.update(src_dict)
```